# Api\SearchCriteriaInterface returning products in anchor categories (or not)

Tags: rest-api, catalogsearch, magento2.4.6

Using a module for a mobile app and this code is retrieving search results. However it's completely ignoring anchor categories and I've spend most of the afternoon trying to figure out why not. There's not a great deal of documentation out there about the SearchCriteriaInterface and it's filters but if anyone knows how to make sure all products inside a category are returned and not just the ones assigned to that category?

this is my function right now.

The API passes inside the $searchCriteria function the category_id but it wasn't originally parsed out until we added the first part of the code to establish $category_id.

Any help appreciated.

Regards

```
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {

        $category_id = null;

        $filterGroups = $searchCriteria->getFilterGroups();
        foreach ($filterGroups as $filterGroup) {
            $filters = $filterGroup->getFilters();
            foreach ($filters as $filter) {
                if ($filter->getField() === 'category_id') {
                    $category_id = $filter->getValue();
                    break 2; // Break both loops since we found the category_id filter
                }
            }
        }



        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($collection);

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        $collection->addMinimalPrice();

        $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);

        $collection->load();

        $collection->addCategoryIds();
        $this->addExtensionAttributes($collection);
        $searchResult = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
        $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
        $searchResult->setItems($collection->getItems());
        $searchResult->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());

        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $product) {
            $this->cacheProduct(
                $this->getCacheKey(
                    [
                        false,
                        $product->getStoreId()
                    ]
                ),
                $product
            );
        }

        return $searchResult;
    }
```